# Retrieve Data from JSON using Dojo Datagrid

Tags: json, dojo

I need to retrieve JSON data and display using dojo datagrid. My JSON is like this

```
var data = {
   "key":[{
         "key1": "info1"},
    {
         "key2": "info2"},
    {
         "key3": "info3"}
]};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: which data you want to retrieve from the json?

Comment: which dojo-version do you use?

Comment: thanks for the response umesh and nozzleman

Comment: umesh i want to retrieve the specific data, for example "key1":"info1" that is only specific part and that with dojo, plz help me out

Comment: its really hard to tell, what the result you expect should look like. How do you want the grid to look like? What have you tried, and if you have tried anything: did you get any errors or unexpected behaviour? Again, in this case a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) migth be the best, to boost you chances to get your question answered properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kinda difficult to answer, because its hard to tell what you have already tried..
I therefore assume, you already got the `DataGrid` to render (using a store, like Daniel Hu suggested) and now you want to "filter" for this specific Entry.

To do so, you migth have to fix the way you set up your `store` like that before:

```
    var yourData = {
        "key": [{
            "key1": "info1"},
        {
            "key2": "info2"},
        {
            "key3": "info3"}
                     ]
    };

    var yourStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
        data: {
            identifier: 'key1',
            items: yourData.key
        }
    });
```

You can now filter the rows that will show up within the `DataGrid` using the `query`-property of the `DataGrid` like this:

```
    var grid = new dojox.grid.Datagrid({
        store: yourStore,
        [some other properties, (especially the structure)],
        query: {key1: 'info1'} // this is where you set you filter...
    }, yourDomNode).startup();
```

Please note, that with the given example data, this would result in a grid with one `row` containing only one `cell` showing "info1". The items-property of the store expects an array, containing object. Each of those object should represent one row, so i guess you got this very concept wrong. What i mean is: `key1` should normally be an object. So it might indeed be 'useful' to have a look at the link recomended by Daniel Hu..

As i already mentioned in my comment: if that doesn't answer your question, it might be useful if you post some code showing what you have already tried and which illustrates the unbeloved behaviour (if it already "behaves" in some kind of way...). Also tell exactly what result you expect and what actually comes out.

Answer (score 0):

A dojo `DataGrid` requires a store. This should help you out:

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/store_driven_grid/